# Chrome Extension: local fonts not importing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fonts

I've read all relative threads and tried everything they say, but local fonts are still not properly loading in my custom chrome extension

popup.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ‘SourceSansPro-Bold’;
  src: local('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: SourceSansPro-Bold;
}
```

manifest.json

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf"]
```

I also tried importing them as follows, but that didn't work either

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ‘SourceSansPro-Bold’;
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: You have a weird quote mark character `‘`, try replacing it with a standard one `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code was copied from Medium, which formats single and double quotes strangely. The comment from wOxxOm was the correct answer. I simply needed to replace the quotes with correct ones.